# Modify jQuery to only trigger specific CSS based on width of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I'm currently using the below jQuery to make the header sticky and fixed in position when the user scrolls down the page but I only want `#logo` set to `display: none;` on screen widths less than 768px (I'm using a variety of stylesheets and media queries already).

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        if( jQuery(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                jQuery('.stickyheader').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                jQuery('.stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
                jQuery('.stickyheader #logo').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
                jQuery('.stickyheader').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                jQuery('.stickyalias').css('display', 'none');
                jQuery('.stickyheader #logo').css('display', 'block');
        }
});
```

How could I only trigger `jQuery('.stickyheader #logo').css('display', 'none');` for this scenario please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off adding/removing a class, and in your CSS file:

```
@media all and (max-width:768px) {
    .hide_if_under_768px {display:none}
}
```

In general it's a bad idea to put raw CSS in your JavaScript (for the same reason that it's generally bad to use `style="css here"` attributes)

Comment: Yes this worked, I simply added `.addClass('hide')` to the if statement and `.removeClass('hide')` to the else statement in my posted code above and then set `.hide` to `display:none` in the CSS. Thanks.